# Spring dao class not found org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, spring, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use a `jdbcTemplate.query` and I get the class not found error. I am using spring-dao 2.0.8 and looked inside the library and couldn't find any `DuplicateKeyException` class indeed. From [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework) this seems to be the latest release for spring-dao.

The code where I am getting the error is:

```
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet)jdbcTemplate.query (query, new ResultSetExtractor<ResultSet>() {
            @Override
            public ResultSet extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return rs;
            }
        });
```

And the stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at DAO.MySQLAccess.getAccounts(MySQLAccess.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 7 more
```

Isn't this the latest release or why is it giving the error in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have a jar missing from the classpath. I guess you're not using maven.

I searched for jars containing this class and came up with this.
http://mavenhub.com/c/org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException/jar

Looks like you need the org.springframework.transaction jar. Or use maven and it should work out your dependencies for you.

Comment: You are right, it was missing `spring-tx` jar. Weird that it was not mentioning it, but asking for a class inside `spring-dao`, which I already have included. I am not using Maven because I already started the project without it and didn't give the time to try it. Never used Maven before.

Comment: I put off trying maven for ages because I didn't have time. Eventually I bit the bullet and wished I'd done it sooner. I just installed the eclipse plugin and tried creating a new project. To be fair the new project wizard is a bit fiddly but once you get the basic project there it makes everything else really easy. I no longer have to hunt around for missing jars. We've also used it to automate unit tests and code generation. Well worth a look IMHO.

Comment: P.S. thanks for the upvote. Your error was a ClassNotFoundException which is usually a missing dependency. It won't tell you which jar you need though, you have to dig around online to find that out.

Comment: Thanks, will try to look into it. I am using Netbeans and will have to look around how to migrate my project to Maven. Will give it some time.