# How to handling the exceptions in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I don't know, how to handle the exception in spring. Can anybody explain  me to handle this?

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException
```

type Exception report

```
message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException
```

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:871)
    com.care.spare.equType.dao.DataListDAO.insertData(DataListDAO.java:49)
    com.care.spare.equpmentType.controllers.CheckExceptionController.saveRecord(CheckExceptionController.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:871)
    com.care.spare.equType.dao.DataListDAO.insertData(DataListDAO.java:49)
    com.care.spare.equpmentType.controllers.CheckExceptionController.saveRecord(CheckExceptionController.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
no
Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.0.RELEASE/8.0.20.B.RELEASEte The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.0.RELEASE/8.0.20.B.RELEASE logs.
```

Comment: application could not find one of your libs in runtime org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring dao class not found org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499200/spring-dao-class-not-found-org-springframework-dao-duplicatekeyexception)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the exceptions configuring in your controllers to use Spring exception handling https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Then you can configure which level of exceptions you want to catch(in your case general Exception would be ok, or if you know the specific exception much better)

```
// Total control - setup a model and return the view name yourself. Or consider
// subclassing ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver (see below).
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
 public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
   logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);
   //Here you can persist the exception or just write in the log
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
   mav.addObject("exception", exception);
   mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
   mav.setViewName("error");
   return mav;
 }
 }
```